# how to lookup and find a value in a specific column in column precedent and put its value in a new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vlookup

I want to do something like Vlookup in pandas, I have a two column data frame, need to check if 2nd column values(B) are valid in 1st column(A), if yes related row and 2nd column value to be inserted in a new column named C, below is sample table:

original data frame is:

```
A      B

a      -
b      a
c      a
d      b
e      d
```

preferred data frame will be:

```
A      B      C

a      -      N/A
b      a      -
c      a      -
d      b      a
e      d      b
```

actually I am beginner in python but in excel this could be easily done by a Vlookup between Column A and B and the result would be reverted in Column C.

below is the code I wrote but it is not complete and does not work:

```
import pandas as pd
excel_file ='D:\Test\Test.xlsx'
data=pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name= 0)
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B'])
lr = df.index.values.astype(int)[-1]
for j in range(0,2):
for i in range(1,lr):
C = []
row=0
for i in df.iloc[:,1]:
    df["C"]=df.iloc[:,0].str.match(i)
    if i == "-":
    C[row]=C.append(i)
    row+=1
elif df.at[i,['Index']]:
    idx = next(iter(df[df['Index'] == True].index), 'no match')
    df.at[i,"C"]=df.iloc[idx,1]



print(df)
```

Comment: Not sure from your sample what are you trying to do

Comment: Lots of ways to do this id personally go with merge

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the Vlookup formula in your question. This will help in understanding what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fill `C` using `np.where` and then map `C` using a dictionary of `A` and `B`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'},
 'B': {0: '-', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'd'}})

df['C'] = np.where(df['B'].isin(df['A'].values), df['B'], np.nan)
df['C'] = df['C'].map(dict(zip(df.A.values, df.B.values)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, VLOOKUP takes a value (say "a") and returns the value in another column (say column "B") whenever this value is matched: `VLOOKUP("a", A:A, 2)`

If this is what you want, you can do that by creating a new (empty) column, then filling the right rows with the right value, for example:

```py
# Create a new column named C
df["C"] = None

# Fill the cells in C for which the column A matches the condition =="a"
df.loc[df["A"] == "a", "C"] = df.loc[df["A"] == "a", "B"]
```

Answer (score 0):

use a list comprehension to do the Vlookup

```
list1=['a','b','c','d','e']
list2=[np.empty,'a','a','b','d']
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':list1,'B':list2})

df['C']=[df.loc[df['A']==x,'B'].values if x in df['A'].values else '' for x in df['B']]
```